# Creating an argument in unix

Tags: shell, arguments

How do you create an argument in unix.

I have to create a shell program that takes in a userid as an argument to see the status of an another user's session.

My problem is with the "take in a userid as an argument"

This is for bash.

Answer (score 2):

For shells, arguments are known as positional parameters i.e. you can insert them one after another after the file name and reach each of them by the position they are inserted at.

The positional parameter 0 is always the script's (file) name and the arguments given started from 1. So you can get the first argument by `$1`, second by `$2` and so on.

For example:

```
% foo () { printf '%s\n' "First: "$1" and Second: "$2"" ;}  

% foo spam egg
First: spam and Second: egg
```

---

To use it in an `if` statement, considering only the first argument `$1` (same goes for other arguments too):

```
if [ "$1" = "foo" ]; then
    ## Dome something
else
    ## Do something else
fi
```

Let's say you have it in a script called `foobar.sh`. Now you can run the script as:

```
./foobar.sh foo
./foobar.sh bar
./foobar.sh blahblah
```

and the values of `$1` will be `foo`, `bar`, `blahblah` respectively in three cases.

Comment: is there an easier to do this. Like I want to use the argument in an if statement

Comment: @shawnedward yeah sure..check edits

Comment: now the problem is how to take userid as as argument

Comment: @shawnedward it is in the answer: *To use it in an if statement,*

Comment: @JacobVlijm what I mean was like how to make an argument called userid from the user on the computer. Like eg. if the name is John, userid will be John. Hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

If I infer correctly from your comments on heemayl's answer, you're looking for a way to get the current user, use `$USER`.

The `$USER` variable returns the current user in string form.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$USER" == <something else> ]; then
    #do something IF the current user is equal to whatever string you compare it to
else
    #do something else IF the current user is not equal to whatever string you compare it to
fi
```

---

*PS: Unix SE isn't really the right place to put questions about homework. Legitimate questions aside, if you have questions about a topic, it's probably best to ask your teacher first.*

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I would ask my teacher if he was good.